# How would I go about creating a custom graphics class for paintComponent to use?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paintcomponent

I've been searching around to understand better what I am trying to do but with little luck. I'm assuming the answer is much simpler than I realize.

I am making a board game for a class project and am using a JPanel to display the graphics (obviously). In the paintComponent, rather than just create everything in one location I'd like to externalize my graphics into a class of there own which I can simply instantiate within paintComponent. Trying to keep everything logically separated and clean as possible.

My Graphics2D looks like it wants a class that implements Shape for its .add() method. If this is correct then, say I implement Shape, what is paintComponent looking for when it paints my shape? Do I need any specific methods or perhaps just use the constructor? Alternatively should all of my graphics class just be using JPanel and using a paintComponent of their own? That feels a bit memory intensive and wrong to me.

All of the examples I've seen so far are all the same...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

  // Create shapes here which combine to form
  // a larger object...
  g2.add(a circle...);
  g2.add(a rectangle...);
  g2.add(other shapes...);
}
```

And what I really just want to do is...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

  // Intantiate robust graphics object from external class.
  g2.add(graphicsObject);
}
```

So I'd ultimately be just adding items in order, a game board surface layer, tiles on top of that, and then game tokens for placement in the tiles.

Words of wisdom and excellent links are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A painting method is for painting only. It should paint the properties of your class. In this case the properties would be the Shapes you want to paint. So you class needs a method to specify the Shapes you want to paint. You don't want to create the shapes in the painting method.

You want to:

1. create an ArrayList to hold the Shapes you want to paint.
2. Then in the `paintComponent()` method you just iterate through the List and paint each shape.

The basic code would be something like:

```
// Create List containing Shapes to be painted

List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapes.add( circle ):
shapes.add( rectangle );

// The custom painting code might look like:

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    for (Shape info : shapes)
    {
        g2d.fill( info.getShape() );
    }

    g2d.dispose();
}
```

So you class would also probably have an `addShape(...)` method to update the shapes List.

For a working example of this approach check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). This example only draws Rectangles but it demonstrates the painting approach.

Comment: It did cross my mind to do something similar to this with a list. I was hoping that JComponent or some interface would afford me this level of functionality but from everywhere I've looked it does not seem so. Graphics programming is something I'm a bit new to still so I guess I should be questioning if my approach to this is even proper to begin with. Given that I have not found a single implementation of this yet it makes me question my logic a bit.

Comment: @ScotMatson `I was hoping that JComponent or some interface would afford me this level of functionality` - This example uses the Shape interface. You can easily create your own Interface that defines a painting method to be invoked for your custom objects. The code posted here is essentially all the code needed to do what you want. I'm not sure what part of your logic you are questioning. You need a data structure to store objects to paint, a method to add objects the that data structure and the painting code to paint each object.