# can i replace labels ? or can i give a GUI and ID ? like in html?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The following code lays out the JLabels using the GridLayout. The arguments to the GridLayout are the following: rows, cols, horizontal gap, vertical gap. In the example below I have 3 pixels wide gap between labels both vertically and horizontally.

To use images instead of numbers, you could pass an ImageIcon to the constructor of the JLabel instead of the text.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class FrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Test");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel("" + i, JLabel.CENTER);
            // JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image_file.png"),
            // JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setFont(l.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            panel.add(l);
        }

        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

in that code the applets build up like a stack , but I want to make it replaceable like if I have a moving robot and I only want to replace the label where the robot moves instead of building a whole new grid ? or can I do that with any other GUI in java ?

Comment: you could also just change the text on the label

Comment: Or simply swap ImageIcons.

Comment: yea but it gets hard if there's blocks on the way and more like AI stuff -_-

Comment: Maybe using a `JPanel` with custom graphics is easier for your application? See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716632/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-custom-graphics-class-for-paintcomponent-to-use.

Comment: good thinking man , thanks , idk why people gave me -1 , that's lame people cant even leave me alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest to use an array of `JLabel` to keep track of the references of each label.

```
JLabel[] labels = JLabel[16];
```

Then, when an event happens, you could use the [`JLabel#setIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) method to change the Icon dynamically.

Comment: done , can u give it a +1 as useful and clear? that person did -1 reduced my reputation and cant even give feed back any more -_- thanks again.

Comment: @MohamedGabr No problem I did it :) Glad it helped you

Comment: you are the best , thumbs up!!